# I want to validate the hypothesis that trend follows from social to search to sales

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook, data-science, hypothesis-test

I have three datasets with me. Social , Search and sales dataset. I have to validate the hypothesis that trend follows from social to search to sales. I am also asked to find the latency and if the latency is same among all the theme ids. I am also supposed to pictorially represent the transition between them

Social dataset has claim id, published date, and number of posts
Search data has claim id, date, platform and search Volume
Sales data has claim id, date, sales dollars value

Any help with this would be much appreciated. Answer through python preferred.
Even steps to proceed will be helpful

Comment: Would you please provide data sample And what you've done so far to try to solve the problem?

Comment: @SergedeGossondeVarennes I have tried creating a lag dataset but not sure where to proceed from thereon.